# Cannot execute U-SQL script from ADF: ScriptPath should not be null

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql, custom-activity

We are trying to run an U-SQL script from a ADFv2, but there is an error preventing the execution. Considering that MS documentation regarding this issue is not helpful, I am again asking in SO for some help fixing this issue.

1. The initial problem is how to deploy the U-SQL script to the ADLA. We could not find anything helpful and ended up just copy-paste the script on ADLA and on an Azure Blob Storage, in 2 formats: .usql and .txt. (this can also be one of the problems).
2. We created the ARM according to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics), but it is failing with an error: `ScriptPath should not be null` which is odd since this value is already specified even on the Linked Service and also on the activity.

Below are the LS and activity we have created:

LinkedService:

```
{
    "type": "linkedservices",
    "name": "LinkedServiceofAzureBlobStorageforscriptPath",
    "dependsOn": ["[parameters('dataFactoryName')]"],
    "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account>;AccountKey=<key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
            }
            "scriptPath": "container\\script.txt"
            //"scriptPath": "https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container/script.txt"//"wasb://container@storage/script.txt",
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
{
            "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
            "typeProperties": {
                //"script": "master.dbo.sp_test()",
                "scriptPath": "container\\script.txt"//"scriptPath": "https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container/script.txt"//"wasb://container@storage/script.txt",
                "scriptLinkedService": {
                    "referenceName": "LinkedServiceofAzureBlobStorageforscriptPath",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "degreeOfParallelism": 3,
                "priority": 100
            },
            "name": "CopyFromAzureBlobToAzureSQL",
            "description": "Copy data frm Azure blob to Azure SQL",
            "linkedServiceName": {
                "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            }
        }
```

Also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474039/2004799) but still with no success.

This is a dummy script that we are testing:

```
@a =
    SELECT *
    FROM(
        VALUES
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        ),
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        ),
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        ),
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        ),
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        ),
        (
            "Contoso",
            1500.0
        ),
        (
            "Woodgrove",
            2700.0
        )
        ) AS 
              D( customer, amount );
OUTPUT @a
TO "/data"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")+".csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

but it would be great if you could point to some more complex example with some code behind in the script.

Thank you!

**Update 26.01.2018**

After consulting with MS regarding the deployment of usql, we came with a combination of powershell commands:

- we execute a script that uploads the .dll that are located in the bin of the u-sql assembly on a folder on the Datalake;
- then loop through the directory and create each of the assemblies separately;
- for the u-sql scripts we have created them as stored procedures on the Datalake Analytics and upload a simple u-sql script that executes those procedures with the needed parameters;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the script path in the linked service.

The blob linked service should just be:

```
{
    "name": "Blob Name",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=etc"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "Your IR Ref",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the activity reference the script using the container and file name like the below with the reference name for the linked service.

```
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "U-SQL1",
            "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 20
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "scriptPath": "u-sql1/Test",
                "degreeOfParallelism": {
                    "value": "5",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "priority": 1,
                "compilationMode": "Full",
                "scriptLinkedService": {
                    "referenceName": "Your Blob Ref",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            "linkedServiceName": {
                "referenceName": "Your ADLa Ref",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            }
        },
```

For info, I've ignored the MS documentation and created this JSON using the new dev UI as I have private preview access. The above has been tested and works as I used it in a blob post here:

https://mrpaulandrew.com/2017/12/20/controlling-u-sql-job-aus-with-azure-data-factory-v2-pipeline-parameters/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the script path from "container\\script.txt" -> "container/script.usql" and now it is working. Also I had a problem with the definition of the Blob LS(will post it in a more clear answer). Can you point me at some tutorials on how to deploy an u-sql script with dependent .dll (part 1 of the question) and also running an u-sql procedure, since it requires the scriptPath? Every sample I found does not have it.